# Mysterious vertical scrollbar appearing

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I am currently working on a website, whose URL is http://lathamcity.com/

The problem that is befuddling me is that when some, but not all, new items are shown, a vertical scrollbar appears, despite there being no content going off the page.  Not only is it bothering me because it is mysterious, but it also looks unprofessional and shifts the text in the header a tiny but noticeable bit.

The effect is visible if one clicks "In Development" or any option in the second menus so far available (all options bring up the same div).

The jQuery code for when an item in the first menu is selected is as follows:

```
var headerHeight = $('#headerTable').height();
$('#selectStart').offset({left: 0, top: headerHeight});
var select1Width = $('#selectStart').width();
var select2Width = select1Width + $('.selector2').width();
$('table.selector2').offset({left: select1Width, top: headerHeight});
$('table.selector2').hide();
$('td.selector1').click(function() {
    $('td.selector2').css({'background-color': '#3B3133'});
    $('table.selector2').hide();
    $('div.pane').hide();
    var choice = '#' + $(this).attr('data-choice');
    $(choice).show();
    $(choice).offset({left: select1Width, top: headerHeight});
    $('td.selector1').css({'background-color': '#3B3133'});
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#61434A'});
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's only a vertical scroll? I get a horizontal one in FF.

Comment: Was messing with firebug and if i get rid of left and top styles of `table id="selectProjects"` it helps. Not sure what the answer is... I would just use `div`s

Comment: I would suggest you use Div instead of table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you do not understand how `position` works.

To explain what happened, try removing `position: relative;` and you will see how the 3rd-level submenu will be below the browser window, hence causing the scrollbar to appear. When you changed the `top` and `left`, it is changed relatively.

That is also why as maxisam suggested, putting `position: absolute;` fixes it.

There are of course many ways to solve it, but now you know the reason.

I suggest this page for some quick lessons on CSS positioning: [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think I understand a lot better now, and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the elements on the page (that you show on click) is overflowing.  Add this CSS rule and the scroll bars will no longer appear:

```
html { overflow:hidden;}
```

Another way to fix the problem would be to find the offending elements and ensure they don't overflow the bounds of the parent container.

Comment: That solved the problem; however, it didn't solve the mystery, and furthermore I would like people to be able to scroll if, for instance, they are not using the full screen and need to scroll just to see the normal setup.

Comment: I think you should mark SyaZ's post answer instead of this one (since he spent time to explain it, but I didn't). I think set `overflow:hidden;` for html is a bad CSS design. Just like you said what if you need to use scroll bar at somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `position: absolute;` for the sub menus that will pop up after click.